# Can't find data source from dbml generated code

Tags: c#, dbml

I inherited a website and I am trying to find out how a dropdownbox on the site gets filled. The only clues i have to this are two snippets of code...one written by the programmer, one generated from what I thing to be the dbml tool.
Heres the written code:

```
            this.area.DataSource = db.GetAreas();
            this.area.DataTextField = "Name";
            this.area.DataValueField = "PRODPOOLID";
            this.area.DataBind();

            this.area.Items.Insert( 0, new ListItem( "Select area...", "-1" ) );
```

the other from the dbml. Here's where it fills the list (as found through debugging)

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="RAW.GetAreas")]
        public ISingleResult<GetAreasResult> GetAreas()
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
            return ((ISingleResult<GetAreasResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
```

the web.config file doesn't specify a table just a database, which is unconnected to this function.
Is there a way for me to find the table this "area" box is being filled from? Either through code or debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will typically in dbml not gone see any table in the web.config all you are sre going to see is the conetion string. The above `this.area.DataSource = db.GetAreas();` show that there is a stored procedure called `GetAreas` which then get generated on the dbml with    `public ISingleResult<GetAreasResult> GetAreas()`